# php post dynamic redirect and prevent form resubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am currently having an issue with the back button in my browser and developing a way to hide the resubmit data warning.

After using the POST method to submit data to php I want to redirect to the location /recipe and once there I wish to use the ID submitted from the post method to search the database for the particular ID to display the data :

```
echo '<div class="text-center"><pre><h4>';
echo '<form action="" method="post"><button type="submit" name="/recipe"'; 
echo 'value="';echo $id; echo '"class="btn-link">';
print_r($doc[title]);
echo '</button></form></h4><p/><p/>';
echo '<p/></div>';
```

The Post event handler looks like this :

```
//PATH for clicking recipe
if(isset($_POST['/recipe'])) {
    recipeMethod($log,$user);  
} else {

}
```

So php delivers this form with data from the database->you click the button and it posts the ID of the database element to /recipe so you can view just that element on the next page. This all works as expected...however when you click the back button it reveals a "resubmit the form" warning. Iv looked around stackoverflow however every solution involved using

`header("Location: http://example.com/page2.php");`

Using this type of redirect just meant the page would redirect to a standard page with no ID being posted and no way for my database to search for the content that i had posted. Does anyone know a way to both submit the ID from my form when the button is clicked, and prevent the resubmit warning from even appearing?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: use get instead of post as long as it doesn't contain sensitive information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ID to redirect URL

`header("Location: http://example.com/page2.php?ID=123456");`